# Magento static block not showing up after I changed the identifier

Tags: static-block

please help. I changed the identifier of static block on CMS, and now it's not showing up on the web page. I wonder how do I know the name of the original static block that I have changed.

Comment: You can find it from code. go to file which is call on page.

Answer (score 0):

There is no revision history for static blocks, so if you cannot remember the original identifier, your options are:

- retrieve it from a database backup
- create a test environment with clean database and install your theme and extensions there (assuming the block was part of the theme)